# qt/pyqt how to share data between two models

Tags: qt, design-patterns, architecture, model, pyqt

Suppose, that you're writing an office application for accounting. Your customer is a bakery, it employs a set of bakers, who cook pies.

You make 2 spreadsheets:

1. First one presents a table (bakers x days), where each cell contains the number of pies, cooked by each baker each day.
2. Second one is (bakers x data), it presents personal data of bakers, such as salary, telephone number etc.

Each spreadsheet corresponds to a custom `QTableModel` and `QTableView`.

Now, I want to present an API to the customer, so that he can programmatically change his data. I want my program to have a console; through it user will be able to modify the storage of bakers' data, called `Bakers`, which both models use to draw data from.

To add a new baker to `Bakers`, user should call `Bakers.add()`; I'd like it to traverse all models and call `insertRow()` method of each of them.

But here comes the problem: in `insertRow()` implementation you should call `beginInsertRow()`, then actually add new baker to `Bakers` and then call `endInsertRow`. That way I'll end up having a baker inserted twice, cause `insertRow()`should be called for each model. Could you suggest a way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: use sql data base and QSqlQueryModel/QSqlTableModel.

Comment: Why not have `Bakers.add()` insert the rows into all models, rather than having the models call `Bakers.add()`?